# Folder named "........." (all dots) with inaccessible contents

Tags: windows-7

I named a folder `.........` and forgot about it.

When I came back to it, inside the `.........` folder is another folder named the same (which I did not create) but none of the original files.

Inside the second `.........` folder are all the files and sub-folders I put initially (*with normal names*). However, I cannot access these files and sub-folders using Windows Explorer or the command prompt. The properties of the folder say that the folder opens with `Windows shell common dll`.

I tried moving the contents out and I tried renaming the folder, but in both cases I get an error saying "*The folder is open in another program*". Process Explorer says that nothing has the folder open.

All this is in Windows 7. Does anybody have any idea how to fix this? I just want access to the files and folders. I've Googled about it but found nothing.

Comment: Before you do anything else about this issue, run `chkdsk /r c:` in the command line (you'll have to reboot and it may take few hours if your filesystem is damaged), then run full antivirus and antimalware scans. (I can recommend Microsoft Security Essentials and Hitman Pro)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First up, I'll show everybody else how to set up an environment like this using a command prompt:

1. Create a folder with a normal name and `cd` into it. Suppose the full name of this folder is `C:\path\test`.
2. Create a dot-named folder in `test` with `md \\?\C:\path\test\....`. Interestingly enough, `cmd` won't let you `cd` into it - it just puts you back in `test`. Windows Explorer shows this folder as containing itself, but when you go into the second layer, nothing appears.
3. Create a file in the dot folder with `echo Ah! > ....\a.txt`. Windows Explorer shows this file in the second dot-named folder (which we didn't create!).

Now to tear it down and save the files:

#### If the dot folder has a short name

1. Make sure you're `cd`'d into the normal-named containing folder (`test` in the above scenario). I recommend keeping Explorer closed to avoid locking issues.
2. Run `dir /x` to get the short name of the dot folder. For me, it's currently `8A9C~1`, but it seems to change when I re-run the procedure.
3. Run `xcopy 8A9C~1\* . /e` to move all the contents of the weird folder into the normal folder. You should put in the actual short name of your dot folder.
4. Verify that the files and the folder structure are intact in the normal folder (`type a.txt` should produce `Ah!`).
5. Empty out the dot folder with `del /s /q 8a9c~1`.
6. Torch the dot folder and its now-empty subdirectories with `rd /s /q 8a9c~1`.

#### If the dot folder does not have a short name

1. Open an administrative command prompt. `cd` to the folder containing the dot folder.
2. Run `mklink /d normal \\?\C:\path\test\....` to create a symbolic link named `normal`.
3. Use Windows Explorer to move all the contents of `normal` (which points to the contents of the dot folder) out into a reasonably-named place.
4. Use Windows Explorer to delete the now-empty `normal` faux-folder.
5. Back in the command prompt, run `rd \\?\C:\path\test\....` to remove the dot folder.

All your files are now safe in a normally-named folder. In the future, you might want to avoid naming folders with only dots.

Comment: there is no short name displayed for the folder, unfortunately

Comment: @lsaw I have updated my answer with an alternative method.

Comment: Is this a feature? Or a bug?

Comment: @RogUE The Windows shell and normal API do not support file or folder names that end with `.`. NTFS has no problem with such names, so it's possible to get into these weird states where there's nothing wrong with the file system but programs can't get into certain places.